# CSS - can't position nav links height right and get rid of additional margin between image and main header navigation bar

Tags: html, css

So I just can't get rid of this little additional margin between image and navi bar. Image has set to have 2% margin, but between image and navibar there´s more margin. And adding padding to the navi links as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOG90Q8EfRo) at 28.00 the guy sets `margin: 0 auto;` to nav list. That does not work for me. He uses nav with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, I just used `<nav></nav>` tags and `<a href="#">link</a>` to create menu. How to fix this margin error and move links up and down on menu bar?

CSS

```
body {
   background-image: url('lgrey.jpg');
   color: #000305;
   font-size: 90%; 
   font-family: Arial, Georgia, Verdana;
   line-height: 1.5;
   text-align: left;
}

.body {  
    margin: 0 auto;  
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;  
 }


.mainheader img {    
   width: 25%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 2% 0;
}

.mainheader nav {            
    background-color: dimgrey;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;   
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
   margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .mainheader nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

   }
```

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>responsive</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

    </head>

   <header class="mainheader">
      <img src="furnitur2.jpg">

  <nav id="nav1"> 
      <a href="#">Avaleht</a>
      <a href="#">Meist</a>
      <a href="#">Asukoht</a>
      <a href="#">Teenused</a>
      <a href="#">Galerii</a>
      <a href="#">Kontakt</a>

      </nav>
     </header>

  <div class="maincontent">
    <div class="content">
       <article class="topcontent">
          <header>
            <h2><a href="#" title="First post">First Post</a></h2>
      </header>

      <footer>
        <p class="post-info">Selle posti autor on Otto Oliver Olgo</p>
      </footer>

      <content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </content>

         </article>
     </div>
   </div>

         <aside class="topsidebar">
           <article>
             <h3>Ülemine sidebar</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum ja nii edasi ma ei maleta mis ladina keelsed                                            
                </p>
              </article>     
           </aside>

       <aside class="bottomsidebar">
         <article>
            <h3>Ülemine sidebar</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum ja nii edasi ma ei maleta mis ladina keelsed                                            
                </p>
              </article>     
           </aside>

 <footer>
   <p>Copyright &copy: 2015 5toneface. All Rights Reserved</p>
 </footer>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry - forgot - if I now add to css next properties:

.mainheader nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

Then padding left and right works, but links are not moving up or down

Comment: kindly add your style.css or come up with html editor jsfiddle.net so that we can view it exactly what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

The image tag is displaying inline with the content which seems to leave extra space at the bottom of it for natural padding.

If your img tag is updated to display as a block element in the css the space goes away:

```
.mainheader img {    
    width: 25%;
    margin: 2% 0 0;
    display: block;
 }
```

To adjust your links you could:

```
.mainheader nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    /* Set line-height to same as height will center text vertically */
    line-height: 35px; 
    /* inline block make the whole height clickable */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px; 
}
```